# Why does downvoting hurt my reputation (but upvoting does not help it)?

Tags: support, voting, reputation, down-votes

I feel that legitimate downvoting is disincentivised by the rep penalty. What are the reasons this penalty exists?

Comment: The title indicates you may be interested in why up voting doesn't give you a point or two, but the body has no such implication. I think you will get information more in line with what you're looking for if you either remove the parenthetical from the title, or edit the body to ask why you don't get points for up voting.

Comment: @JoelHarmon The parenthetical is there as a justification for the question, pointing out the contrast. The meat of the concern is certainly not there though.

Comment: [Isn't this a dupe](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3698/22566)?

Comment: @Korvin Good spot. I agree it probably is. That question now has the down-votes tag.

Answer (score 13):

Downvoting *is* disincentivised (it's not just you), and that's deliberate. [The help page on downvotes](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down) says this: “Voting down answers is not something we want you to take lightly, so it is not free.”

Stack Exchange's engineers want us to think carefully before we downvote something, want us to make sure it's worthwhile. A tiny -1 ping to our reputation is just enough to make that happen. I *could* go downvote every single post for fickle reasons, but that tiny little penalty gently gamifies me into only downvoting when it's serious and necessary.

Downvotes on questions are ***free*** however. That's the case because we badly need people to downvote bad questions so that the site only has good material to respond to, and don't want them thinking twice about whether it's worth it. The downvote help page links to [Optimizing For Pearls, Not Sand](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/) to explain this philosophy.

---

Upvotes don't come with penalties nor benefits (such as a corresponding +1 rep for the voter). We want people to [vote early and vote often](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/19/vote-early-vote-often/), so there's no cost. There cannot be a +rep benefit for upvoting though. Reputation is strictly only awarded for those activities which concretely benefit the site: posting good questions and answers, making good edits (as a low-rep user), and accepting an answer that's helped you. People want to do things that give them reputation, reputation rewards need to be implemented with the careful question: “what would happen if people did this as much as possible without stopping?” If we were all just contributing awesome questions and answers, good helpful edits, and accepting the answers that solved our problems, we've got a lot of constructive users. But if people were voting constantly on everything, we compromise the upvote as a signal of “this is good” because it could also mean “this is crap but I wanted +rep for voting on it” and our scoring system would collapse.

Comment: This answer would be improved by talking about the question's observation that upvoting is not penalised, and discussing why downvoting is treated differently from upvoting (similarly to how you've already explained why downvoting *answers* is different from downvoting *questions).

Comment: @BESW How does that look?

Comment: While I like how this answer is phrased, I think the question is [a dupe](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3698/22566).